# Include in gulp file external files

Tags: node.js, gulp

I have a gulp file having the following structure:

```
// =============== helper JS stuff =============== 

var production = false;

var folders = {
    folder1: "./myfolder",
    folder2: "./myfolder2"...
}

function Module() {
 this.jsFiles = ...
 this.cssFiles = ...
}

var Modules = [
    new Module({ first: module }),
    new Module({ second: module })...]

// =============== Tasks =============== 

gulp.task('myTask', function(){ 
    //work with modules
});
```

I would like to separate (gulpfile.js) taks from other pure custom javascript things (in special from modules list) in (at least) three files:

```
Solution

-- gulpFolder

---- consts.js       // declare here dirs/folders/other constants
---- module.js       // helper 'Module' object declaration 
---- listModules.js  // a list of 'Module's to work with (to update)

-- gulpfile.js       // tasks definitions, works with the module list
```

Is it possible to just "import" into `gulpfile.js` just simple javascript files like described bellow (like `consts.js`, `module.js` etc)?

I tried to use the requireDir

```
var requireDir = require('require-dir');
...
var dir = requireDir('./website/!gulp'); // ?
```

but this code didn't seem to really "import" jsfiles... As I understand, **`require`** and **`requireDir`** works only with nodeJS modules/files...

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't turn `consts` and `module` into modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In node, each javascript source file is a separate namespace. When you `require` a file, you can only access what that file has `export`-ed. This means you'll have to `export` from each of your other files. For example:

**module.js:**

```
function Module() {
 this.jsFiles = ...
 this.cssFiles = ...
}
module.exports = Module; // export!
```

**listModules:**

```
var Modules = [
    new Module({ first: module }),
    new Module({ second: module })...]

module.exports = Modules; // export!
```

Then in your main file you can access the code like this:

```
var Module = require("gulpFolder/module.js");
var Modules = require("gulpFolder/moduleList.js");

gulp.task('myTask', function(){ 
    //work with modules
});
```